# making a curved line in evolus pencil project

Tags: evolus-pencil

I'm having a little problem here in pencil project. I'm trying to put a curve line.

I tried this "free line" icon because I believe it is used to make curved lines. But it just appears as straight line when I use it, and I can't find the button or option to make it curved. Where can I find it? How can i make it curved?

Answer (score 5):

It seems the curvy mode (just like the lines from multiple straight segments mode) only has an effect once both ends of the line are attached to connectors on other objects:

[image: Pencil screenshot showing two buttons connected by a curvy line]

Note that you need to choose connectors that mandate a specific orientation of the connected line, such as the connectors on the edge of an object. The central connector won't do:

[image: Pencil screenshot showing a highlighted edge connector on a button and a line attached to the center of another button]